# cakephp model association is not working

Tags: cakephp, associations

I have the table 'posts' and 'users':

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
`name` varchar(255) default NULL,
`date` datetime default NULL,
`content` text,
`user_id` int(11) default NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
`name` varchar(100) default NULL,
`email` varchar(150) default NULL,
`firstname` varchar(60) default NULL,
`lastname` varchar(60) default NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

and the model classes:

```
<?php
 class Post extends AppModel {
var $name = 'Post';
 var $belongsTo = array(
'User'=>array(

            'className'=>'User',
            'foreignKey'=>'user_id',
            'conditions'=>null,
            'fields'=>null)
 );
 }
 ?>

<?php
class User extends AppModel {
 var $name = 'User';
 var $hasMany = array('Post');

 }
?>
```

I am testing using var $scaffold.
However, after I add some users, I can only see an empty select menu in the add post page, which means the association is not working. I don't know what is wrong with my code. Please help me out. 
Thank you very much!

Comment: Try changing to `var $belongsTo = array('User');` since you're following convention there's no need for you to define those extra keys, so lets just eliminate them from the equation.

Comment: I tried using var $belongsTo = array('User'); but still dose not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
See the below url:-

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1042/belongsTo
http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1043/hasMany


//Try This for belongsTo :--


<?php
class Profile extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Profile';

    var $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
                    'className' => 'User',
                    'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
                )
        );
    }
?>

Or

<?php
class Profile extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Profile';

    var $belongsTo = array('User');
    }
?>


//For hasmany

<?php
    class User extends AppModel {
        var $name = 'User';
        var $hasMany = array(
            'Post' => array(
            'className' => 'Post',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'conditions' => array('Comment.status' => '1'),
            'order' => 'Comment.created DESC',
            'limit' => '5',
            'dependent'=> true
        )
    );
}
?>
```

Comment: @savedario you saved me thanks. The camel case is very important in case of models for shared web servers. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I am starting with cakePHP too and banged my head for some time before I realized that the "conventions" require the Model filename to be CamelCased.
Try using:

```
Post.php
User.php
```

otherwise it seems the models are totally ignored.